# How am I able to rotate around?

Tags: interface

Why can't I rotate around in Blender? I am holding my middle mouse button down but it is not working. I have to use the thing in the corner as of right now.

Comment: May be you messed up something in the preferences. Reset the settings.

Comment: I already tried that. Every time I click the middle mouse button it says move to collection. How do you think I can fix this?

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed it changing some settings in my mouse's software.